# What is the smallest amount of Ether?

Tags: ether

For example, the smallest amount of Bitcoin is one Satoshi or 0.00000001 BTC. What is the smallest amount of Ether and what is it called?

Comment: Related: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/363/why-is-ether-divisible-to-18-decimal-places

Comment: Is there a minimum amount you need to own?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The smallest unit of ETH is called Wei, and is 1x10^-18 ETH, i.e.

```
1 Wei = 0.000000000000000001 ETH
```

Comment: The units in the equation need to be swapped :)

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

It's wei(1 ether = 10^-18 wei).
There are several other sub units like gwei, and finney.
You can see all the sub units with their values from here,

https://etherchain.org/tools/unitConverter