# What is the smallest amount of LINK?

Tags: chainlink

Similar to [What is the smallest amount of Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13811/what-is-the-smallest-amount-of-ether), what is the smallest amount of LINK?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest amount of LINK has the same denomination as ETH, but is known as Juels instead of Wei.

It is 1x10^-18 LINK, i.e.

```
1 Juel = 0.000000000000000001 LINK
```

Which is the same as the ETH/Wei relationship

```
1 Wei = 0.000000000000000001 ETH
```