# Why dont Ethereum use bigger base system?

Tags: security, addresses, privacy

My reasoning is that a bigger base system would allow for same level of security with less characters, allowing for a better user expereince. Since you would need to memorise a smaller number to do a transaction.

Comment: See [What fixed or float point math libraries are available in solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83785/what-fixed-or-float-point-math-libraries-are-available-in-solidity).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple answers for that. However most famous reason is for arthemtic divison. EVM doesn't support floating points so every ether is equal to 1e18. The ethers you are looking in the interface are converted into the numbers using the javascript functions such as:

```
ethers.utils.formatUint(1e18, "ether);
```

For more reasons read the following material:

[Why is ether divisible to 18 decimal places?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/363/why-is-ether-divisible-to-18-decimal-places)

[Why most ERC-20 Tokens Have 18 Decimals?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38704/why-most-erc-20-tokens-have-18-decimals)

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: I think I might have not explanied myself well enough. Private keys are written in the hexadecimal base system (from 0 to f). Why hexadecimal and not a base system greater? Would it not reduce amount of characters needed for keys and addresses?

Comment: [Why Hexadecimals](https://medium.com/@savas/why-do-we-use-hexadecimal-d6d80b56f026)

You can read this article. It is pretty much same reason everywhere.